# How to dismis SearchDisplayController's keyboard?

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to create iPad application, which has two `UIView`s (like `UISplitView`). There is `UISearchDisplayController` in the "master" side.

I need to dismiss keyboard by tapping outside (either "master" or "detail" side). Now I can only dismiss the keyboard by tapping dismiss button in it or by tapping to `UISearchDisplayController`.

**SOLVED** by the help of **rmaddy**:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
...
...
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
...
...
- (void)dismissKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.searchDisplayController.active = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the search controller's `active` property to `NO` to dismiss it.

Comment: thanks, but how could I know "was tapped outside"?

Comment: You could add a tap gesture recognizer to the other views.

Comment: Your `dismissKeyboard` is going to be called multiple times per tap. You should add a parameter to the method (the `UITapGestureRecognizer`) and check the gesture's state. Only act on the gesture if the `state` is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. See the docs for `UITapGestureRecognizer` for details.

Comment: @rmaddy how can I dismiss it from other UIViewController?

Comment: The same way. Use a gesture to detect the tap. Of course you then need to send a message to the other view controller. There are lots of ways for that including a direct method call.

Comment: @rmaddy: ok, I understand it, but there is a UITableView too. Now I can not select tableViewCell, because "dismiss" method calls